# Mule DataWeave How to merge header and lines in json

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Need to merge header with lines in generic manner.   Header and lines before the next header belongs to one object . For one header_n there can be many lines_n .
example header_0 and line_1 and line_2 are one object. For one Header_n there can be many Line before we find another header.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "Header_0": {
      "Recordtype": "1"
   
    }
  },
  {
    "lines_1": {
      "RecordType": "2"
 
    }
  },
  {
    "lines_2": {
      "RecordType": "2"
      
    }
  },
  {
    "Header_3": {
      "Recordtype": "1"
     
     
    }
  },
  {
    "lines_4": {
      "RecordType": "2"
  
    
    }
  },
  {
    "lines_5": {
      "RecordType": "2"

   
    }
  },
  {
    "lines_6": {
      "RecordType": "2"
     
  
    }
  },
  {
    "lines_7": {
      "RecordType": "2"
   
            }
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "Header_0": {
            "Recordtype": "1",
            "LineItems": [
                {
                    "lines_1": {
                        "RecordType": "2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "lines_2": {
                        "RecordType": "2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Header_3": {
            "Recordtype": "1",
            "LineItems": [
                {
                    "lines_4": {
                        "RecordType": "2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "lines_5": {
                        "RecordType": "2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "lines_6": {
                        "RecordType": "2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "lines_7": {
                        "RecordType": "2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

If not possible in Dataweave, let me know what other option we can try in mule.

Comment: Can you fix your output json? It is not valid

Comment: @HarshankBansal Output json modified.

Comment: Why is `Header_8` not in output?

Comment: @KarthikRajaJ What is the index that you mentioned? There is no key called index. And please say DataWeave, not DWL, which is not a standard term.

Comment: Harshank Bansal , modified the output.
aled , Edited the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following DataWeave

It basically loops through the input array, adds the "Header" records to the output array `accumulator` and adds the subsequent "Lines" to the last added header in the output array

```js
%dw 2.0
import update, index from dw::util::Values
output application/json

fun isHeader(record) = record..Recordtype[0] == "1"

fun addLineItemToHeader(headerRecord, lineItemRecord) = 
    headerRecord  update {
        case .LineItems! -> ($ default []) << lineItemRecord
    }

---
payload reduce ((item, acc = []) -> 
    if(isHeader(item)) acc << item
    else acc update index(sizeOf(acc)-1) 
        with ($ addLineItemToHeader item)
)
```